# How to extract hours from time stamp column in pandas data frame and convert to float type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

Hi I want to create a liner regression prediction model and want to get a time as a independent variable. My data frame has a time stamp and I wanted  to extract the hours from it and put in to separate column as float data type. Highly appreciate your support on this . Thank you.
Time stamp
12/1/2021 8:39
7/10/2020 13:47
1/11/2020 11:53
4/10/2020 12:33
11/10/2020 12:40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `hour`:

```
#DD/MM/YYYY H:M
pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').dt.hour.astype(float)
```

---

```
#MM/DD/YYYY H:M
pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.hour.astype(float)
```

Or extract `digits` between space and `:`:

```
df['Time stamp'].str.extract('\s+(\d+):').astype(float)
```